Stripe SetupIntent automatic payment method shows SEPA for USD connected account
While upgrading our Stripe API Version (and thus also our java library version) i wanted to make use of the newly added automatic_payment_method field for SetupIntents we use with for connected Accounts.
We manage multiple connected Accounts in different parts of the World (USA, Europe and Australia) and thus our active payment method defaults include SEPA, iDEAL etc.
I was a bit surprised to learn that Stripe seems to offer SEPA Direct Debit for a connected Account in USA, for a customer who has their address in USA as well.
Is there a way to tell Stripe that this is a USD transaction and thus it automatically hides payment methods, which are not applicable (even though it is enabled in the connected account)?
This is how we create the SetupIntent
SetupIntentCreateParams.Builder paramsBuilder = SetupIntentCreateParams.builder()
      .setCustomer(customer.getStripeId())
      .setAutomaticPaymentMethods(AutomaticPaymentMethods.builder()
          .setEnabled(true)
              .build())
      .setOnBehalfOf(stripeConnectedAccountId)
      .setUsage(SetupIntentCreateParams.Usage.OFF_SESSION);


where are you testing from? The PaymentElement doesn't really use the customer's address to filter PaymentMethodTypes. So if you're testing your code from the EU it's normal to get Sepa Debit.

@Tarzan But how does this make sense? We have international customers paying for services in the US, while being in Europe themselves. They need to pay in USD and thus even if they physically are in Europe, SEPA should not be an option.

SEPA DD is available to US Stripe accounts as international payment methods.
https://stripe.com/pricing/local-payment-methods
As such, the only way to natively restrict what payment methods are automatically rendered on the payment intent would be with the currency, however Setup Intents have no notion of currency.
Frankly, if you need to not display SEPA for Setup Intents made on behalf of connected accounts, I'd recommend reverting to using payment_method_types instead of using automatic_payment_methods.

Thanks for the answer, although it is a bit dissatisfying. I feel like all the information could be available to make a more sophisticated decision by Stripe about this, but oh well.

You could look into Payment Method Configurations - which are a new feature and relate to an instance of the active payment method settings on your connected account. https://docs.stripe.com/connect/payment-method-configurations Honestly, I feel like this is a more complicated solution to payment_method_types still

Yeah i will keep the payment_method_types for now. It really isn't that bad, but it feels like it could be a bit better. Thanks for your efforts!
